# Should I put commas after my matrices in a paper?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, article-writing

When I need to put a matrix in my paper, I usually use $$  to center it on my page, and I usually describe something about the matrix immediately after, e.g., "which has real entries..."

should I put a comma after the matrix?  Is that the standard thing to do when writing a paper?

There's a bit of spacing between the matrix and the comma, so it looks a bit weird, but I also want to be grammatically correct, too.

What do you think?

Thanks,

Comment: Some people add the commas because sometimes the sentence continues after the matrices. If you mean listing some matrices, I think that it only depends on your liking.

Comment: If it's the end of a sentence, put a period after the matrix and before the `$`. If you're following with a nonrestrictive phrase such as "which has...", then use a comma. Use nothing if the flow of the sentence doesn't require it. Test: if the matrix were inline (not displayed) and were instead just a letter $A,$ then use just what you would after $A.$

Comment: This is something I've wondered for a while... +1

Answer (score 2):

Well, from a grammatical point of view, it seems that a comma is mandatory. But let us make some practical experiments...

**Version 1**: no comma.

Consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{d_1&0&0&0\\0&d_2&0&0\\0&0&d_3&0\\0&0&0&d_4}
$$
which has real entries on the diagonal.

**Version 2**: with a comma.

Consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{d_1&0&0&0\\0&d_2&0&0\\0&0&d_3&0\\0&0&0&d_4},
$$
which has real entries on the diagonal.

**Version 3**: with a comma and an extra space.

Consider the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{d_1&0&0&0\\0&d_2&0&0\\0&0&d_3&0\\0&0&0&d_4}\ ,
$$
which has real entries on the diagonal.

**Version 4**: with a comma and an extra space, matrix in scriptsize.

Consider the matrix
$$
{\scriptsize\pmatrix{d_1&0&0&0\\0&d_2&0&0\\0&0&d_3&0\\0&0&0&d_4}}\ ,
$$
which has real entries on the diagonal.

**Conclusion**. This is definitely opinion based, but I have a slight preference for version 3. Version 4 could be occasionally used, for instance for a very large matrix.